# Regex: allow for the occurrence of a certain character up to one time

Tags: regex

I want to search for a specific (DNA) string 'AGCTAGCT' and allow for the occurrence of one (and only one) mismatch (signified as 'N').

The following are matches (no or one N):

```
AGCTAGCT
NGCTAGCT
AGCNAGCT
```

The following are not matches (two or more Ns):

```
AGNTAGCN
AGNTANCN
```

Comment: Do you need to use regex? Why not a loop?

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: It appears to me that `N` stands for one of `A`,`T`,`C` or `G`.  Not a literal `N` but the wrong nucleobase in that position.  Most of the answers are assuming a literal `N`.  Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

In any language you could do something like this

```
var count = str.match(/N/g).length; // just count the number of N in the string
if(count == 1 || count == 0) { // and compare it
   // str valid
}
```

If you only want a regex, you could use this regex

```
/^[^N]*N?[^N]*$/
```

You can test if the string matches the above regex or not.

Comment: i think this can be simplified to `^[^N]*N?[^N]*$`

Comment: he wants to match 'AGCTAGCT', not any string.

Comment: A minor variation of this answer would be `/^[^N]*(N[^N]*)?$/`. I find this style easier to understand.

Comment: Again, this is looking for a literal `N` character in the string.  DNA sequences contain no `N` characters.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg yes. But OP has given no logic, per which dna string has to be matched.

Comment: It's a DNA sequence.  Although there is no tag for DNA, it still has meaning.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg DNA as in De-Oxyribo Nucleic Acid? I know it has a meaning but I'm by no means a scientist. I may give a regex to match a "DNA" string, but want to know how to match it, what's the pattern, which OP should have put in his post. Anyway, if you know how the pattern of a dna string should be, please tell me and I could include that in my regex

Comment: It appears to me that he wants to match the sequence 'AGCTAGCT', but with at most one incorrect neucleobase.  There is not "the pattern of a dna string", but there are patterns *in* DNA sequences.  These are important in many areas of study.  For example, enzymes are used to cut strands of DNA when matches are found.  This is without error -- but sequencing DNA strands may induce errors in reading, leading to questions such as this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python, you can make it without regex:

```
myList = []

for word in dna :
    if word.count('N') < 2 :
        myList.append(word)
```

and now, if you want to generate all the DNA, i dont know how DNA takes letters, but this can save you:

```
import itertools

letters = ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'N']

for letter in itertools.permutations(letters):
    print ''.join(letter)
```

then, you will have all the permutations you can have from the four letters.

Comment: I don't see how you accept only 'AGCTAGCT' with at most one N.

Comment: `word.count('N') < 2` can be `one N or no N`

Comment: he only wants 'AGCTAGCT', not any string with at most one N.

Comment: no, he wants to excludes any word that have 2 or more N, Quote: `The following are not matches (two or more Ns):`

Comment: "I want to search for a specific (DNA) string 'AGCTAGCT'"

Comment: from the list you returned `AGCTAGCT` contains zero N, while the others contain only one N (the N replacing the letters for 0 to length(word)+1 ), which the loop is for.

Comment: it is not a list, it is a regular expression.

Comment: I don't believe that searching for a literal `N` answers the question.  He states that this is a DNA sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead at the start to check for the strings whether it contains two `N`'s or not.

```
^(?!.*?N.*N)[AGCTN]{8}$
```

I assumed that you string contains only `A`,`G`,`C`,`T`,`N` letters.

```
^(?!.*?N.*N)[AGCTN]+$
```

Or simply like this,

```
^(?!.*?N.*N).+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dW6eV8/1)

Comment: Again, this is looking for a literal `N` character in the string. DNA sequences contain no `N` characters.

Answer (score -3):

I think a regular expression is not the best choice for doing this. I say that because (at least to my knowledge) there is no easy way to express an arbitrary string to match with at most one mistake, other than explicitly considering all the possible mistakes.
being said that, it'd be something like this

```
AGCTAGCT|NGCTAGCT|ANCTAGCT|AGNTAGCT|AGCNAGCT|AGCTNGCT|AGCTANCT|AGCTAGNT|AGCTAGCN
```

maybe it can be simplified a bit.

**EDIT** 
Given that N is a mismatch, a regular expression to accept what you want should replace each N with the wrong alternatives.

```
AGCTAGCT|[GCT]GCTAGCT|A[ACT]CTAGCT|AG[AGT]TAGCT|AGC[AGC]AGCT
|AGCT[GCT]GCT|AGCTA[ACT]CT|AGCTAG[AGT]T|AGCTAGC[AGC]
```

Simplifying...

```
(A(G(C(T(A(G(C(T|[AGC])|[AGT]T)|[ACT]CT)|[GCT]GCT)|[AGC]AGCT)|[AGT]TAGCT)|[ACT]CTAGCT)|[GCT]GCTAGCT)
```

**Demo** replacing N with wrong choices https://regex101.com/r/bB0gX1/1.

Comment: he wants to match AGCTAGCT, with at most one N

Comment: yes, but he has to write them all by hand and count using his  eye!

Comment: if you find a shorter RE please post it.

Comment: If this regular expression is to be used in a computer program, the program can also generate the expression.  However, I agree that a regular expression is almost certainly not the best solution.